# What to do with all 9 answers pretty much the same

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-answers, answer-quality

I'm taking a look at [a question with 9 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572657/hoe-set-class-to-div-tag#18572657) (now removed), which *all* seem to be pretty much the same.  Should any be downvoted/flagged, and if so, which ones?

Comment: Are any of them wrong, or offensive, or blatantly copied without attribution? Then no, none of them need any action.

Comment: It could be the *question* was too simple to begin with, to attract so many answers that are the same. I see it already attracted downvotes, probably for that very reason.

Comment: Let it be. They're all too basic anyway so don't really worth upvote. Anyhow, looks like they all missed the spot.

Comment: "If not, then no, none of them" surely @MartijnPieters ;)

Comment: Last sentence in question "`text.className = 'thumbnail';` doesn't work" and accepted answer "use `text.className = 'thumbnail';`" Sigh...

Comment: Just wait a moment, it should be deleted soon (I hope).

Comment: @hayd They comment under the answer they accepted `I have 2 buttons Each have js handler. I mix up its` (sic) so I guess it only didn't work as they had messed up something else.

Comment: Another similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502675/how-to-get-the-index-value-of-the-current-selector-in-jquery : 6 almost identical answers, and the problem cannot be reproduced anyway...

Answer (score 4):

No, usually user answers and in the means time other user post the replies, If you observe there is not much time difference(except some) in these answers. So No one is wrong. Downvote is for wrong/Incorrect answers.

Comment: Downvotes are for *unhelpful* answers, which is different from wrong/incorrect.  An answer can be correct and still be unhelpful.

Comment: If you hover over the down vote arrow, you will see a text saying `This answer is not useful` and a correct answer is always useful. If it is not useful it is wrong/incorrect.

Comment: That is false.  Just because an answer is correct doesn't mean it solves anyone's problem.  An answer can be correct but be entirely off topic, be an inappropriate solution to the problem, be hard to understand, etc.  An answer can also be mostly right but have one or two errors that aren't particularly germane to the problem at hand, making it incorrect (in part) but still generally useful.  While there is a *correlation* between correctness and usefulness, they are not synonymous.